# IE7, HTML - Why does simply moving the mouse outside of a container correct an overflow problem?

Tags: html, css, mouseevent

I have a page that asks a number of questions, each question being shown or hidden depending on the answer to the previous question.

If I do a bit of to'ing and fro'ing I can end up with the last question appearing below it's container - the container has not resized when the question was revealed. However, I simply have to move my mouse out of the container and it resizes and the layout is as expected.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: if you have javascript that adds or removes a class on mouseover/mouseout it might be triggering a repaint.

Comment: We need to see your javascript or CSS which is handling hover events, or a link to your page.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the *hasLayout* issue on Internet Explorer 7. You can try to correct it by adding *zoom:1* to the element.

Read more about *hasLayout* at [On having layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)